# How to implement non-generic trait on a struct with a generic parameter

Tags: generics, rust

I am using the [`I2CDevice` trait](https://github.com/rust-embedded/rust-i2cdev/blob/master/src/core.rs) which is defined in an external crate like this:

```
pub trait I2CDevice {
    type Error: Error;
    // members
}
```

Neither it nor any of its members contain any generic arguments.

I am creating a decorator for any `I2CDevice` implementation which delegates to an inner/concrete `I2CDevice`, adding console printing for diagnostic purposes:

```
struct debugDeviceDecorator<'a, T: I2CDevice<Error = LinuxI2CError> + Sized + 'a> {
    device: &'a mut T,
}

impl I2CDevice__A__ for debugDeviceDecorator__B__ {
    type Error = LinuxI2CError;

    fn read(&mut self, data: &mut [u8]) -> Result<(), Self::Error> {
        println!("read: data: {:?}", data);
        self.device.read(data)
    }

    // etc.
}
```

I can't figure out what to put in place of `__A__` and `__B__`.

When I use no generic arguments whatsoever, I get compiler errors: *Expected 1 lifetime parameter* and *Expected 1 type argument.*

My best guess then is to leave `__A__` blank because the definition of `I2CDevice` requires no generic arguments, and then to mirror the type argument used for the `debugDeviceDecorator` struct itself in place of `__B__` like:

```
impl I2CDevice for debugDeviceDecorator<'a, T: I2CDevice<Error=LinuxI2CError> + Sized + 'a> { }
```

I get the compilation error: *error: expected one of `!`, `(`, `+`, `,`, `::`, `<`, or `>`, found `:`*, which occurs on the colon (`:`) that begins the type constraint on the generic argument `T`.

Perhaps the compiler thinks that I'm trying to constrain `T` in a manner which diverges from the constraint in the struct definition itself, so instead I try:

```
impl I2CDevice for debugDeviceDecorator<'a, T> {}
```

Which results in the errors *undeclared lifetime* for the lifetime parameter, and *undefined or not in scope* for the type argument itself, at which point I cannot figure out how to proceed.  I would assume that the lifetime and the type argument are defined by the future, as yet nonexistent code that will some day initialize a `debugDeviceDecorator` struct, values which cannot yet be known and seem to me as though should not prevent this existing code from compiling.

I can see the compiler needing some information about the type of `self.device` used within the functions of the impl, but I feel like my first guess in which I mirrored the struct's expanded type definition in my impl declaration should have provided that.

Comment: @ardave FYI, you can put something between `impl` and `I2CDevice`.

Comment: *which occurs on the colon (:) that begins the type constraint* — **why** would you go out of your way to retype in English what would have been more clearly expressed by simply *copy-and-pasting the error*?

Answer (score 4):

You should re-read *The Rust Programming Language*, specifically the section on [how to implement traits for generic structs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/traits.html#trait-bounds-on-generic-structs). A *lot* of hard work has gone into that documentation so that people can get started in Rust easier.

The book will show you the proper syntax for how to define a trait for a struct:

```
impl<'a, T> I2CDevice for DebugDeviceDecorator<'a, T>
    where T: I2CDevice<Error = LinuxI2CError> + Sized + 'a
{
    // ...
}
```

Note:

1. You have to declare the two generic values (`'a` and `T`) before you can use them.
2. There's nothing special about the fact that the trait has no generics.
3. Types in Rust use `PascalCase`, not `camelCase`, so I've changed the name.
4. I switched to a `where` clause because it's too hard to read the bounds when they are crammed into the generic declaration.